# Can I use MongoDB to store sessions in Symfony 2?

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, session, nosql

Is it possible to use MongoDB to store sessions in Symfony 2? If so, how?

Comment: Your starting point can be here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php

Comment: @ItayMoav How is that related to symfony 2? Does sf2 use that for its sessions?

Comment: I wrote this is only a starting point. I am pretty sure Symphiny under the hood is using the $_SESSION too.

Comment: Well I think it's not that simple.

Comment: If you change the handler for the $_SESSION directly, it is hidden from Symphony, as far as Sym she can't really tell, or care what SESSION handler is being used.

Comment: Side note: yes it's possible, I've done it in a project here but I just need to find time to dig it out....

Comment: @richsage Oh great, let's hope you can find it =)

Comment: @HappyDeveloper answer added :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done this with Mandango, but it should be easily convertable to use eg Doctrine's MongoDB ODM or similar.  I made a start, but it hasn't been tested and I'm fairly sure it should be passed something different to a Mongo instance ;-) I've added placeholders or example code where appropriate eg:

```
public function __construct(\Mongo $con, ...)
```

which I'm fairly sure will need to change :-)

Code is up on Github at https://github.com/richsage/Symfony2-MongoDB-session-storage - PRs welcome when you get it working!

Essentially, I've extended the NativeSessionStorage class, and adjusted the various methods to handle inserting, retrieving and updating session records in my Mongo database where appropriate.  The class needs to be configured as a service, with the appropriate dependencies added in, and then this service is passed to the session configuration. Et voila :-)

Comment: Wow thanks, I hope I can understand the code. I'll check it out when I get home.

Answer (score 8):

Just because I think the question is not really answered. In Symfony 2.1 is now possible to store session data in MongoDB with the MongoDbSessionHandler which is included in the HttpFoundation component.

Main configuration of config.yml looks like:

```
session.handler.mongo:
    class: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\MongoDbSessionHandler
    arguments: [@mongo, %mongo.session.options%]

mongo.connection:
    class: MongoDoctrine\MongoDB\Connection
    factory_service: doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager
    factory_method: getConnection
    calls:
       - [initialize, []]
mongo:
    class: Mongo
    factory_service: mongo.connection
    factory_method: getMongo

mongo.session.options:
    database: app_session
    collection: session

framework:
    session:
        handler_id: session.handler.mongo
```

Read more here: http://blog.servergrove.com/2012/11/05/storing-sessions-in-mongodb-with-symfony2/

Comment: The thing is that this solved the problem, but I would love to add a small comment: session.handler.mongo, mongo.connection and mongo should go in the services section, and mongo.session.options in the parameters section